# How to let TypeScript know I am using an specific interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have using TypeScript and have two interfaces, Interface1 or Interface 2, for example:

```
export interface Interface1 {
  propA: string;
  propB: string;
}

export interface Interface12 {
  propA: string;
  propC: string;
}
```

And the method that returns objects implementing one of the possible interfaces and looks something like this:

```
doSomething: (state): Interface1 | Interface2 | null => {
      if (state === 1) {
        return ObjectImplementingInterface1;
      }
      if (state === 2) {
        return ObjectImplementingInterface2;
      }
      return null;
    }
```

Afterwards, I want to use the result of that method and use a property only existing in Interface2, for example:

```
const varExample = this.doSomething(this.s);
      if (varExample) {
        if ('type' in varExample && varExample.type === 'Interface1') {
          this.importantResult = varExample.propA;
        }

        if ('type' in varExample && varExample.type === 'Interface2') {
          this.importantResult = varExample.propC;
        }
      } else {
        this.importantResult = 'someValue';
      }
```

The compiler does not let me use the propC and throws the following error:

```
Property 'propC' does not exist on type '(Interface1 | Interface2) & Record<"type", unknown>'.
Property 'propC' does not exist on type 'Interface1 & Record<"type", unknown>'.
```

How could I force TypeScript to know that this objects if definitely an object implementing Interface2?

Comment: `propC` exists on `Interface12`. I don't see an `Interface2` definition.

Comment: Search for TypeScript discriminated unions. If you set it up right, your `if (varExample.type === 'Interface2') { ... }` should narrow the type of varExample so it knows the type inside the if block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force TypeScript to use a particular interface or type by using what's called type assertion or type casting.
The way we usually do so is by using the **as** keyword.

```
this.importantResult = (varExample as Interface2).propC;
```

Comment: This was precisely what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Typescript is unaware what type `varExample` has - you can inform TypeScript that it implements `Interface2` by using the [as keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to assert the object's type:

```js
this.importantResult = (varExample as Interface2).propC;
```